# subplots() got multiple values for argument 'nrows' while looping through subplots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, figure

I am trying to create a piece of code that lets me loop through as many subplots as I need to create from a machine that spits out a variable amount of data. Sometimes I will have a few plots, sometimes I'll have more than 30. The code seems to work well except that when I run it, my plots always end up looking squished. When I try to pass the ncols argument or the nrows argument to my code, it says:

subplots() got multiple values for argument 'nrows' while looping through subplots

Here is my code:

```
conditions = 15 
colors = ['purple', 'blue', 'plum', 'green']
condition_names = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']

rows=3
cols=5
fig, axes = plt.subplots(conditions, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(18,25), nrows=rows, ncols=cols)



q = 0
c = 0
d = 0
total = len(En_cols)

try:
    for i in En_cols:
        q = q
        lines = En_cols
        axes[d].errorbar(data=En_means, x=Num_x_axis, y=En_means[lines[q]], yerr=En_devs[lines[q]], c=colors[c], ecolor=colors[c], capsize=5, marker='s',linestyle ='--', label=condition_names[c])
        q = q + conditions
        c = c + 1
        axes[d].errorbar(data=En_means, x=Num_x_axis, y=En_means[lines[q]], yerr=En_devs[lines[q]], c=colors[c], ecolor=colors[c], capsize=5, marker='s',linestyle ='--', label=condition_names[c])
        q = q + conditions
        c = c + 1
        axes[d].errorbar(data=En_means, x=Num_x_axis, y=En_means[lines[q]], yerr=En_devs[lines[q]], c=colors[c], ecolor=colors[c], capsize=5, marker='s',linestyle ='--', label=condition_names[c])
        q = q + conditions
        c = c + 1
        axes[d].errorbar(data=En_means, x=Num_x_axis, y=En_means[lines[q]], yerr=En_devs[lines[q]], c=colors[c], ecolor=colors[c], capsize=5, marker='s',linestyle ='--', label=condition_names[c])
        q = q + conditions
        c = c + 1

        c = 0 
        d = d + 1
        q = q + 1
        q = q - conditions*4
        continue
except IndexError:
        pass
```

Is there a way that I can reshape my figure so it does not look terrible?
Thanks

Comment: What is `conditions` used for? Also what is `En_cols`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both `conditions` as a positional argument and `nrows=` as a keyword argument, that's why you get that error.

I suggest deciding how many columns you want (could be proportional to the number of conditions) and then calculating the number of rows

Note however, that `subplots()` will return a 2D array of axes. But you can traverse it as if it were 1D using `axes.flatten()[i]`

e.g.:

```
import math

conditions = 16 
cols = 5
rows = math.ceil(conditions/cols)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

[image]